# Responsive design toggle using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have this responsive design using Bootstrap's grid system:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 view">
        <div id="panelviewer">  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 panel1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">ONE</a></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 panel2"><br><br><a href="javascript:void(0)">TWO</a></div>           
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    max-width:600px;
    overflow:visible;
}
.view {
    border:dashed #333 1px;
}
.row {
    overflow:visible;
}
#panelviewer {
    position:relative;
}
#panelviewer .row {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.panel1 {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    background:#ccc;
    vertical-align:top
}
.panel2 {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    background:#eee;
    vertical-align:top
}
@media (min-width: 990px) {
    #panelviewer {
        width:671px;
    }
}
.open {
    right:100%;
    margin-left:-34px;
}
```

I'm trying the create a toggle effect bringing a div into, and out of, view. I can't seem to the get the measurements right. Specifically, I have these questions:

1. Why is a 100% `right` offset combined with a `margin-left` value not bringing the entire div into view?
2. Why is the div's width not fitting to the parent (desktop only)?
3. Why is there a 4px gap between the two divs?

Take a look at (and resize) the [JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7HcQ8/4/) to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Terry's answer, I ended up doing away with the `padding` on the parent div `view`. This brought the divs into line with the exception of the 4px space.

I then used the `<!-- -->` hack to remove it:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 panel1">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">ONE</a>
   </div><!--
--><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 panel2">
      <br><br><a href="javascript:void(0)">TWO</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HcQ8/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Some answers to your question:

1. This is because there are negative margins influencing the position of each panels from Bootstrap CSS
2. Padding is declared in the parent, and when specifying 100% width on the panels, they will stretch to the content-box width of the parent, which excludes paddings.
3. This is because you have declared the two elements as **inline-block** elements: this means that the browser will treat them as inline elements when laying them out, and interpreting any whitespace between them as space: so the two elements are treated like two separate words.

---

What I would suggest is that you reset the margins and paddings for the `.row` element, and then instead of playing with both `left` and `right` positions, stick to one. Declare the individual panels as block-level elements, and use absolute positioning. However, since absolute positioning takes them out of the document flow, you will need to declare an explicit height for the parent.

```
.row {
    overflow:visible;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; /* Or any desired value */
    margin: 0;
}
#panelviewer {
    position: relative;
}
.row > div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.panel1 {
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
}
.panel2 {
    display: block;
    background: #eee;
    left: 100%;
}
.open {
    left: -100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7HcQ8/6/

Comment: your solution works only when the document width is smaller than 990px (i.e. mobile). In desktop, box `ONE` expands beyond the borders of the parent div and the toogle doesn't bring `TWO` into view.

Comment: Then change your media query to set the width on the parent element, `.container`, instead http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7HcQ8/7/

Comment: thanks. is there no way not to be constrained by an explicit `height`?

Comment: The height will have to be set in one way or another — and of course you can explore other options to set it. It depends on what you want.